# ElasticSearch agg on substring of data

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do avg() on a substring of data. Is it possible in ES?
Here is my script

```
{    
  "size": 0
   ,"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "term": {"app": "att"} }
        ]
      }
    }
   ,"aggs": {
    "clients": {
      "terms": {"field": "client"}
        ,"aggs" : {
                "_avg_" : { "avg" : { "field" : "ms" } }
            }      
      }      
    }
}
```

The problem is that field "_ms" looks like:

```
It took: 100 ms ......
It took: 104 ms ......
It took: 102 ms ......
```

So, I'd have to pull 100, 104, 102 and so on before I do "avg"

Comment: Do you have tons of data? I'd strongly suggest to reindex and store it properly.

Comment: I don't have a ton of data, but pretty sure I have no saying in re-indexing process. The app dumps the data this way.

Comment: Fix your app and store it properly then. You're just making things more complicated this way. Another way would be creating a separate field, that would store same value initially, but apply char filter, so only numbers remain. Then you could do your aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot re-index your data and absolutely "have to" work with that data, you can use a `script` in your `avg` aggregation. Since you don't have that much data, the performance will not suffer too much.

The Groovy script you can use would be simply `doc['ms'].value as Integer` which would coerce the string into an integer and use the integer value to perform the average.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "app": "att"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "clients": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "client"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "_avg_": {
               "avg": {
                  "script": "doc['ms'].value as Integer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that in order to perform this query you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I just found out that strings will be formatted this way: "It took: 100 ms; range: 0 to 1 seconds;". Just tried your solution, but it did not work. Is it because there are multiple integers present?